# Which variables to choose in a change of variables for a PDE

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable, linear-pde

I want to solve the following PDE:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-3 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x+y$$
with boundary condition:
$$f(x,-2 x)=\sin \left(x^{2}\right)$$
Using a change of variables. How can I determine the correct variables in such a transformation?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-3 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x+y$$
System of characteristic ODEs (Charpit-Lagrange) :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}=\frac{df}{x+y}$$
A first characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}$ :
$$3x+y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation from :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}=\frac{(x)dx+(-\frac13 y)dy}{1(x)-3(-\frac13 y)}=\frac{xdx-\frac13 ydy}{x+y}=\frac{df}{x+y}$$
$$xdx-\frac13 ydy=df$$
$$f-\frac12 x^2+\frac16 y^2=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_2=\Phi(c_1)$ :
$$f-\frac12 x^2+\frac16 y^2=\Phi(3x+y)$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the boundary condition.
$$f(x,y)=\frac12 x^2-\frac16 y^2+\Phi(3x+y)$$
Condition :
$$f(x,-2x)=\sin(x^2)=\frac12 x^2-\frac16 (-2x)^2+\Phi(3x+(-2x))$$
$$\Phi(x)=\sin(x^2)+\frac16 x^2$$
Now the function $\Phi$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $(3x+y)$ :
$$f(x,y)=\frac12 x^2-\frac16 y^2+\sin\big((3x+y)^2\big)+\frac16 (3x+y)^2$$
After simplification :
$$f(x,y)=2x^2+xy+\sin\big((3x+y)^2\big)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have been told by my professor that this PDE can likewise be solved with a 'variable transformation' by substituting $$\phi \equiv x+\lambda_{1} y, \quad \psi \equiv x+\lambda_{2} y$$
Where lambda are some constants. However, I cannot find examples online where this method is applied, and I do not know how to choose the correct values for lambda.

Comment: Since your professor gave you the transformation to be done : $\phi=x+\lambda_1y$ and $\psi=x+\lambda_2y$ why don't you do it at first? The transformed PDE must contains $\phi,\psi,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ but no $x,y$. Of course you don't know the values of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ at the begining. After the transformation caried out, simplify the PDE in choosing favourable values of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.